# Post value can not get in controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

When i am trying to get the post value from my controller,
i am always getting null.

But if i check the post value, i can clearly see that there is post value, but somehow i am not getting that value in my controller.

Do anyone knows where is the problem and why i am not getting the post data ...!!!

**Html ---**

```
<form method="post">
    <div align="center" class="col-md-10">
        <input  type="text" id= "input" name="input" >
    </div><
    <div class="form-group"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search">
            Search
        </button></div>
</form>
```

**javascript --**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = {};
            data['input'] = $('#input').val();
            // Submit data via AJAX§
            $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
            }),
              return false;      
    });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller ---**

```
function contentAction(Request $request) {

    $tic = microtime(true);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->request->get('input');
    print_r($data);
```

Comment: I don't know `Request` too good, but is there a function for `post` as well? So you use the function `get`, but you're sending the form with `post`

Comment: Why are you using `$request = $this->getRequest();`? You are already setting the request by using `Request $request`

Comment: And what is `$request->$request` for? Could you do a `var_dump($request);` at the top of your controller (before you do anything else) and give us the results?

Comment: Looking at your `Html` and `jQuery`, at first it is not possible for the ajax call (Click event to fire). Check that you have used `class selector (.search)` and in html you have used `id (search)`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this is the easiest answer:

```
function contentAction(Request $request) {
    $tic = microtime(true);
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $data = $request->request->post('input'); //here use post instead of get
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use method: "POST" in your ajax function

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = {};
            data['input'] = $('#input').val();
            // Submit data via AJAX
            $.ajax({
            url: '/home',
                    method: 'POST', // <-- Method POST
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {

                    }
            }),
              return false;      
    });
    });
</script>
```

And then in controller:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$data = $request->request->post('input');
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following code:

```
$data = $request->request->get('input');
```

with this:

```
$data = $this->request->post('input');
print_r($data);
```